# Iterate over List of inherited class objects

Tags: java, loops, inheritance

I have a `List<Task> tasksToDo` that holds lots of different objects. Some of which are not `Task` objects but `TimingTask`objects which is a class that is inherited from the `Task` class. My question is that when I try to iterate over this list using the following:

```
for(Task theTask: tasksToDo)
{

}
```

How can I use the methods that is inside of a `TimingTask` object, if the object is of that type? The `TimingTask` object type has a method called `getAdd` which is only present in that type. Therefore when I try with `theTask.getAdd` I get an error as the `getAdd` method is not present within the `Task` class type.

Comment: If you want to treat `Task` objects like `TimingTask` objects, move `getAdd` into `Task`.

Comment: I agree with @Smutje. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Answer (score 2):

Its bad form to be iterating over an array of base class objects and trying to treat them as their derived class.  generally you want to iterate over the base class objects because you want to treat them as that object type.  putting in logic that is specific to a derived class makes the loop code more confusing to maintain.

Comment: I understand this, however i fail to see a better way of dealing with this scenario. If i have different task types that needs to be iterated over as i dont believe all those types should be in one class. That would only make that class confusing instead of this loop

Comment: The earlier comment about adding the method to the alternative. but in your case here it seems the only real option is the instanceof check.

Answer (score 1):

use [instanceof](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31):

```
for(Task theTask: tasksToDo) {

    if (theTask instanceof TimingTask) { //if theTask is an istance of the class TimingTask
        TimingTask theTimingTask = (TimingTask)theTask;
        //now you can use theTimingTask.getAdd();
    } else {
        //theTask is not an instance of the class TimingTask
    }
}
```

Comment: Since Java 14 you can delete this line`TimingTask theTimingTask = (TimingTask)theTask;` and instead code `if (theTask instanceof TimingTask theTimingTask) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Task theTask: tasksToDo)
{
  ((TimingTask)theTask).getAdd();
}
```

If you want to check first the theTask is an instance of TimingTask, use `instanceof`:

```
if(theTask instanceof TimingTask)
    ((TimingTask)theTask).getAdd();
```

Answer (score -1):

Ther is a possible solution for your problem

```
for(Task theTask: tasksToDo){
       if (theTask instanceof TimingTask){
          TimingTask theTimingTask = (TimingTask)theTask;
          //Your treatments for your theTimingTask objects
       }else{
          //If you need other treatments for only the Task objects and your other different objects
       }
    }
```